# how to create slide out menu in iOS step by step for beginner

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6, xcode7

i am trying to create slide out menu in iOS but there is no any article found me step by step slide out demo. plz guide me to create slide out menu step by step.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: For your further investigation; try to search for "hamburger menu".

Comment: are you looking to make an own Slidemenu or would u consider using a third party which is easily incorporated and customisable?

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path Check this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Add a Slide-out Sidebar Menu in Your Apps
http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to show a slide in/out view with animation.

```
-(void)showSlideInView
{

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.35
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     self.slideInView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL completed){

                 }];
}


- (IBAction)hideSlideInView:(UIButton *)sender
{

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                     self.slideInView.frame = CGRectMake(-self.view.frame.size.width, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL completed){
                 }];
}
```